# Branches, cuts and branch points of arccos(z)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[My attempt to a solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCAVz.png)

Once I get this, I can't find a domain cut by the branch cuts and therefore de branch and branch points.
Is there only one knowing the principal value of the logarithm or there may be more?

Comment: There are branch points at $\pm i$.  How should the plane be cut to define the arccosine?

Comment: Here I don't understand, because the square root inside the logarithm, equated to zero, gives +1 and -1. I thought that the branch points were these two and ∞. However, my teacher tells that the main branch goes from x=0 to x=π. So, why is it ±i?